# why I cant use initialising list to initialise my object?

Tags: c++

```
class Parent {
public:
    int mA;
    void speak(){}
};
class child :public Parent {
public:
    child(int a):mA(a){}//interpreter tells "mA" not a non-static member to child
};
```

interpreter tells "mA" not a non-static member to child,but why?Child  inherit members from Parent,so child must also have mA on itself,am i right?Please, I'm confused!

Comment: Membership is not a transitive relation (not even when coupled with inheritance). You are thinking about the *sub-object* relationship, which *is* transitive, but is about the raw object representations and not the logical structure of the types.

Comment: Please add some code,i don't understand your words,thank you

Answer (score 2):

`mA` is not a member of `child`.  It belongs to `Parent` and must be initialized by a constructor of `Parent`.

```
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(int a) : mA(a) {}
    int mA;
};

class child : public Parent {
public:
    child(int a) : Parent(a) {}
};
```

Comment: `class test124 {
public:
 int mAge;
 test124(){}
 test124(int a) {
  mAge = a;
 }
};
class test2343 :public test124 {
public:
 test2343(int b){
  mAge = b;
 }
};` then why this can be done

Comment: shoudn't child also have a copy of Parent members?That's why i can still let mAge=b in child

Comment: Yes, the members are inherited, but you cannot directly initialize inherited members in an initializer list. You can invoke inherited constructors in the initializer list, but you cannot invoke constructors for members that are inherited.  You _can_ initialize it the way you suggested above, but it's a massive code smell to do that.  It sacrifices encapsulation to gain nothing.